# How to set the shared library soversion at the build-time?

Tags: cmake

This sets the version at cmake-time:

```
set_target_properties(${THIS_LIB} PROPERTIES SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
```

But I use scripts that extract some info from git (is it dirty or a wrong branch, etc).

For example, they can generate a `version.cpp` with all this info at the build-time:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp
    DEPENDS
        ${GIT_COMMIT_DIRTINESS_FILE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -DSRC=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cpp.in
        -DDST=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp
        -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/configure-file.cmake
)
```

So the executable now has various information about the source tree state.

How to do the same kind of operation on the SOVERSION, so in the package the lib would appear as `libmy.so.0.0.1.SHA.~dirty` for example?

Comment: Would `libmy.SHA.~dirty.so.0.0.1` acceptable?

Comment: @Antonio, no, the `0.0.1.SHA.~dirty` is already used as a version number for packaging (CMake+CPack) too. So, the build-time version number generation works fine with both `version.cpp` and CPack. It would be strange to have a different version of the so file.

Comment: Normally, file's configuration is executed at *configure* stage. Why this is not suitable for your case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, because the commit number will change after the configure stage.

Comment: There are ways for forcing project's *reconfiguration* if file `${GIT_COMMIT_DIRTINESS_FILE}` is changed. So you may configure your `version` file on *configuration* stage, and set *soversion* on this stage too. I just unsure that there are ways for setting soversion on build stage, as you want.